# Нужна функция, сокращающая большие числа в python до int 4 байта

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Всем привет. Я портирую необходимый мне ГПСЧ с языка C++ на python. Всё бы ничего, но там вся математика построена на том, что переменные не могут выйти за предел заданного размера. Вот так например выглядит инициализация объекта:

```
    void Generate( unsigned int seed )
    {
        rndNumbers[ 0 ] = seed;
        for( int i = 1; i < periodN; i++ )
            rndNumbers[ i ] = ( 1812433253 * ( rndNumbers[ i - 1 ] ^ ( rndNumbers[ i - 1 ] >> 30 ) ) + i );
        GenerateState();
    }

/*
результат
1812433254 
3713160357 
3109174145 
64984499 
*/
```

На C++ эта функция возвращает числа не превышающие ~4.2 миллиарда. На питоне же она растёт экспоненциально:

```
    def Generate(self, seed):
        # Randomizer.rndNumbers[0] = seed
        Randomizer.rndNumbers.insert(0, seed)
        i = 1
        for i in range(i, Randomizer.periodN):
            buf = 1812433253 * (Randomizer.rndNumbers[i - 1] ^ (Randomizer.rndNumbers[i - 1] >> 30)) + i
           # convert = Randomizer.sign32neg(self, buf)
            Randomizer.rndNumbers.insert(i, buf)
            print(buf)
        Randomizer.GenerateState(self)

# результат 
# 1812433254
# 3284914300205028517
# 5953687907471897995228510841
# 10790661948188992052692469723994213968
```

Я весь интернет перерыл, но так и не нашёл подходящую функцию. Самое близкое что я нашёл была функция

```
def sign32neg(self, value):
    value &= 0x7FFFFFFF
    value = int(value)
    value = ~value
    value ^= 0x7FFFFFFF
    value += 2**32
    return value
```

, но она срабатывает только в половине случаев. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить это.

Comment: Что значит "в половине случаев"? Когда конкретно не срабатывает? Числа вообще должны быть signed или unsigned?

Comment: Вообще непонятно, какая связь между кодом на `C++` и на питоне. Я бы предложил всё сделать в точности как на `C++`, а в конце просто обрезать до нужного числа байт `value &= 0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: seed каждый раз разный, periodN = 624, тип unsigned int предпочтительнее

Comment: [np.uintc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.uintc), [np.geterr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geterr.html), [np.seterr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для unsigned просто обрезаете. Для signed чутка посложнее.

```
unsigned_int32 = lambda value: value & 0xffffffff
signed_int32   = lambda value: ((value & 0xffffffff) ^ 0x80000000) - 0x80000000

print(unsigned_int32(0xFFFFFFFF))  # == 4294967295
print(  signed_int32(0xFFFFFFFF))  # == -1
```

Comment: спасибо, value &= 0xFFFFFFFF помогло

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку входных и выходных данных в вопросе не наблюдается, останемся  только в поле теории без примеров, тестов и конкретного использования.

Я думаю, что [ctype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) это то, что вы ищете. Данный модуль предоставляет типы данных совместимых с C. Их представления и обработку.

Модуль - платформозависим, поэтому читайте документацию и примечания

Пример использования

```py
from ctypes import c_uint32

def func32(data):
    return c_uint32(int(data,32)).value

func32(b"111111111111111111111111111111111111111")
```